# How to identify the impact of one variable's value in the past on the current value of a second variable?

Tags: correlation, predictive-models

I am currently working on analysis problem where I wish to assess the impact of overtime work on sickness levels in a company. I currently have the data stored by week for each employee over the last 2 years.

My hypothesis is the following: Over time (additional work hours) increases the likelihood of sickness for each employee. Null Hypothesis: Past overtime has no impact on sickness levels. 1 row has a similar layout to this:

```
Week 1      Employee A     1 Hour Sick        12 Hours Overtime
```

As each observation takes the current sickness and overtime I am unsure how to create a model which tests the impact of past overtime on current sickness.

If anyone has dealt with this kind of problem before and identified a good statistical method then your advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to review http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251160/how-to-forecast-a-time-series-which-is-dependent-on-different-time-series